# Как сделать из текстового файла список

Tags: python

Пишу бота на python, никак не могу сделать так чтобы он из текстового файла делал список вида `['user1','user2',....]`

```
with open("test_users_list.txt", "r") as a:
    users_names1 = a.read()
    users_names = []
    users_names.append(users_names1)
    print(users_names)
```

выводит:

> ```
> ['drazdobarov5\ndrazdobarov4\ndrazdobarov3\ndrazdobarov2\ndrazdobarov1']
> ```

вот что хранится в test_users_list.txt:

```
drazdobarov5
drazdobarov4
drazdobarov3
drazdobarov2
drazdobarov1
```

Comment: a.read().split('\n')

Answer (score 3):

Используете readlines

```
with open("file.txt") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("test_users_list.txt", "r") as a:
    users_names = a.read().split("\n")
    print(users_names)
```

либо

```
with open("test_users_list.txt", "r") as a:
    users_names = a.readlines()
    print(users_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open("test_users_list.txt") as a:
    users_names = a.read().split("\n")
    print(users_names)
```

У меня есть одно замечание: в `open()` необязательно указывать параметр `"r"`, т.к., файл по умолчанию открывается на  чтение